# magento2 get quote Id from customer

Tags: magento2, quote

How to get quote Id from quote table via Customer Id or email.

I have Customer id & email & i want to check if quote id exist or not how to do that via create new module or programming

What i want : I want to pass customer id & excepting quote data

Any Help much be Appreciated

Comment: what do you want exactly ?

Comment: U want Current Quote id or all quote id which belong to particulate custome?

Comment: @bhavik : i updated my question please check

Comment: @BornCoder   i updated my question please check

Answer (score 4):

You can fetch quote data from quote table by customer id:

```
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
       \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $item, 
        array $data = []
    ) {
          $this->_item=$item;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
```

After than you can get quote data using:

```
$this->_item->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerid)->getData();
```